# Replacing an element with specific text

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change all dd's with specific text, in this example "color" from dd to dt elements.

```
   <dl>
    <dd><a>color</a></dd>
    <dd><a>green</a></dd>
    <dd><a>blue</a></dd>
   </dl>

   <dl>
    <dd><a>color</a></dd>
    <dd><a>red</a></dd>
    <dd><a>orange</a></dd>
   </dl>
```

What would be the best way to go about this?

Thanks

Comment: Select the elements, and change their text. Which part is giving you trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('dd').each(function() {
    if ( $.trim($(this).text()) == 'color' ) 
        $(this).replaceWith($('<dt>' + this.innerHTML + '</dt>'));
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6cBKp/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try using wrap()/unwrap()

```
$('dl dd').filter(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).text()) == 'color'
}).wrapInner('<dt />').contents().unwrap()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/s7yCB/)

Comment: @onetrickpony it does a partial search so if another item contains the  text `red - color` it will be matched by `:contains`